# what does "from MODULE import _" do in python?

Tags: python, import

In the Getting things gnome code base I stumbled upon this import statement

```
from GTG import _
```

and have no idea what it means, never seen this in the documentation and a quick so / google search didn't turn anything up.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`from GTG import _` imports the `_` function from the `GTG` module into the "current" namespace.

Usually, the `_` function is an alias for [`gettext.gettext()`](http://docs.python.org/library/gettext.html#gettext.gettext), a function that shows the localized version of a given message. The documentation gives a picture of what is usually going on somewhere else in a module far, far away:

```
import gettext
gettext.bindtextdomain('myapplication', '/path/to/my/language/directory')
gettext.textdomain('myapplication')
_ = gettext.gettext
# ...
print _('This is a translatable string.')
```

Comment: Hi thanks, this is really helpfull. I was aware of the general 'from BLA import bla' syntax so finding out about this convention was really what I was looking for! Using such a shorthand makes much more sense now. Thank you

Comment: @bp Fair use. Besides, reading the documentation is waaaaay more highly valued in the python culture than asserting property rights is...

Answer (score 4):

This imports the function/class/module `_` into the current namespace.  So instead of having to type `GTG._`, you just have to type `_` to use it.

Here is some documentation:

http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#more-on-modules

It should be noted that you should use this with care.  Doing this too much could pollute the current namespace, making code harder to read, and possibly introducing runtime errors.  Also, NEVER NEVER NEVER do this:

```
from MODULE import *
```

, as it very much pollutes the current namespace.

This technique is most useful when you know you are only going to use one or two functions/classes/modules from a module, since doing this only imports the listed assets.

For example, if I want to use the `imap` function from the `itertools` module, and I know I won't need any other `itertools` functions, I could write

```
from itertools import imap
```

and it would only import the `imap` function.

Like I said earlier, this should be used with care, since some people may think that

```
import itertools

# ... more code ...

new_list = itertools.imap(my_func, my_list)
```

is more readable than

```
from itertools import imap

# ... more code ...

new_list = imap(my_func, my_list)
```

as it makes it clear exactly which module the `imap` function came from.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that `_` doesn't have a special meaning in Python, it's just another letter-like character that you can use to name a variable.

Comment: @Paul,

thanks for pointing this out. I was aware of the general 'from GTG import bla' syntax but the _ confused me.
Now, I previously thought that there would have to be a file _.py in the GTG package folder, but I guess that's wrong.
the '__init__.py' file in the GTG/ folder has the line

'    _ = translation.gettext'

so I guess that is all that _ is then.
Any reason somebody would want to name a function in such a weird way?

Comment: @DavidZ Not completely true. from fibo import * imports all names except those beginning with an underscore (_).

Comment: @Rufus_12 that doesn't mean `_` has any special meaning in the language. The builtin `__import__` function treats it specially, but its syntactic meaning is the same as any letter. You could just as well have an alternate importer that imports all names not beginning with `w`.