# why does this python module import this module as _?

Tags: python

I was looking at some python code and came across this:

```
from gettext import gettext as _, ngettext
```

what is the "gettext as _" doing? it seems as though it's being imported only to be ignored.

Comment: From the documentation for `gettext.gettext()`: "This function is usually aliased as _() in the local namespace".  It's just to avoid visual clutter due to a function that's likely to be called *a lot* in the program.  This is unrelated to the common use of `_` as a dummy variable.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2908444/what-does-from-module-import-do-in-python

Comment: At first sight it looks like, assigning something to `_` makes it to go to nothingness (like `mv something /dev/null/`). But you can assign something to `_` and use it later.

Comment: @jasonharper - thanks. if you want to make that an answer I'll accept it.